# Slider in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, slider, flexslider

I want to make a slider in my custom wordpress theme (using understrap):
I tried using flexslider, had a problem where i could not target the .slides ul for whatever reason. i edited it in my _theme.scss and also tried in the flexslider.css
Why did it work in the inspector, but not in the css / scss files?
This was the first hurdle. The second is, i dont want to have dots below to see what picture i am viewing, i want to have lines , in the right-middle of the picture which shows on an active state the number of the picture currently viewing, for example picture 1 is viewed, show "1" next to the active line.

as this has become impossible to solve with my current skills i am asking you guys to help me out please.

i would use the bootstrap carousel, too. But i am unsure how to edit the above mentioned css to create the desired outcome.

I do not want to use a wordpress plugin as this limits me probably in my decisions. I cannot do "if active state "1" then write "1" next to the picture" or something like that, if you know what i mean.

sorry for putting it really general but thats all i can provide as i have only the non - working flexslider locally installed.

Answer (score 0):

for instant solution you can use option tree plugin.which make the pictures dynamic with them you can use bootstrap  slider.and replace image url option tree plugin code.

Comment: _**I do not want to use a wordpress plugin**_

Comment: that would ruin the smooth slider effect :/ 
the thing is, i dont want to use a wordpress plugin, because i want to a) learn, b) edit it myself to fit my needs, i want to have a horizontal carousel indicator in the middle of the screen. well i think with custom css thats an easier  task and you dont rly need a plugin for this small stuff. im just not good enough yet

Comment: can you please share slider example related  to your slider.what kind of slider you want

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/q96oUC9 , this is all i can provide. it should look like this, simple image in the background

Comment: the question now is, how do i tell the flexslider 
more specific the : flex-viewport ul { } to have 0 padding on the left, because due to some never seen "    padding-inline-start: 40px;" it is not in the right spot. those 40px cannot be changed it says "user agent stylesheet" in the inspector

Comment: Got it working now, wrong embed of css file. First problem Solved :) second one is still up, how to change the carousel indicators as stated